# Can I overnight at the Amsterdam airport to meet someone arriving in the morning?

Tags: legal, airports, airport-transfer, sleeping, ams

My parents and I are reaching Amsterdam airport on different times and dates. I will arrive on 27th at 21.00 from Bergen, Norway and my parents will arrive at 7.55 on 28th April from India.

Can I wait within the airport arrival area for them and sleep over there for the night? I have a flight back to Norway on 28th April at 21.30

Comment: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/amsterdam.htm

Comment: You want to wait for your family in the area before passing custom ? I would be surprised that they would allow you to sleep in that area.

Comment: @Max Especially since Norway is in the Schengen Zone and, thus, you'd never be in the pre-customs area in the first place (unless AMS has some intra-Schengen border controls I'm not aware of.)

Comment: @reirab: Intra-Schengen flights usually arrive in a pre-customs area -- customs is only after the baggage claim. They are not in the pre-_immigration_ area, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, right, sorry. Pre-immigration is what I meant, but it's too late to edit.

Comment: I would not be surprised if you could not find a seat to fall asleep on. But, Amsterdam is close and hostels are not too expensive, while a bed beats a chair hands down.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait in the Arrivals area after customs if you like, although obviously it won't be comfortable. You can also wait around in the Schegen departure lounge, if you are arriving on KLM, and then exit out to meet them when they arrive. The shops and restaurants will be open until a little after midnight. If you are using a low cost carrier I believe they use a different pier which may have reduced departure facilities. Also, if you have any check in baggage it may be removed if it is not claimed within a few hours.

Personally I would find a cheap hotel and meet them in the morning.

Comment: The low-cost pier works the same way, you can go back to the departure area and there are seats there. But it's even smaller and I am not sure whether it closes at night. Also you can certainly meet someone from a non-Schengen flight before customs, in the baggage reclaim area. Passengers from both Schengen and non-Schengen flights (including from low-cost airlines) all go through the same baggage reclaim area (they are connected).

Comment: When it comes to arrival, 1 to 4 just refers to the exit nearest to the place you enter the baggage reclaim area but there is no strict separation. Some years ago I even missed the person that was waiting for me because I left through the “wrong” exit involuntarily. My flight was announced at the exit in front of the luggage belt assigned to it but it was quite far away the place you would exit if you did not need to pick up any luggage.

Answer (score 2):

Sleeping in Schiphol is allowed, but there is very little opportunity to do so on the Plaza side, but I've seen people put sleeping bags and mattresses down there, so there's always that.

There are more than enough benches beyond customs. If you can get to this side, you could also choose one of Schiphol's hotels: [Hotel Mercure](http://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/FoodRelax/AfterPassportControl/Relax/HotelMercureSchipholTerminal.htm) or [Yotel](http://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/FoodRelax/AfterPassportControl/Relax/Yotel.htm). If your flights are on the same booking, this should not be a problem. If they are not, you'll have to see if you can check in at this point.

Of course you can always go to Amsterdam itself. Amsterdam Central Station is a 15 minute train ride, with at least 8 trains going per hour.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point about being on the same booking and the link with hotels.

Comment: They're behind customs.

Comment: Still don't get it. Which flights? You can obviously check in landside.

Comment: No, the hotels are airside. They can only be accessed with a ticket.

Comment: So your suggestion is to go through immigration, collect your luggage, go through customs, check back in and then stay at an airside hotel? How does it matter whether the flights are on the same booking? I am not being critical here, I still have some trouble understanding, maybe you should make your idea more explicit…

Comment: I got the impression OP is transferring. I may be incorrect of course, but I included it. If it is not, he (or she) will need to check in first, as you need to be checked in to use the hotel the website says.

Comment: I don't know, I am really not objecting to anything, but I think you should rephrase your answer to make all that clearer. For example, I am still not exactly sure which bookings you are referring to (the parents' and the OP's, the OP's incoming and outgoing flights?)